# Как обрезать select по символам?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```html
<div style="
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -5px rgba(153,148,153,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -5px rgba(153,148,153,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -5px rgba(153,148,153,1);
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 198px;
    border-radius: 69px 69px 69px 69px;
    -moz-border-radius: 69px 69px 69px 69px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 69px 69px 69px 69px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    left: 147px;
    top: 25px;
">
          <select style="
    font: 11px Arial;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 27px;
    top: 76px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 15px;
    width: 195px;
    left: 25px;
    border: none;
">
 <option hidden>Выберите марку</option>
   <option>SHORT</option>
   <option>LONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONG</option>
  
 </select>
         </div>
```

На месте станд. селекта будет картинка с бэкграундом (в которой есть стрелочка справа 20px).
Задача, при выборе долгого option в выборе обрезать его по символам и ставить 3 точки. А чтобы при развертывании он все еще выглядел нормально. Пробовал подвинуть p-r, вроде выходит как нужно, но как добавить три точки в конце, ума не приложу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Решение можно найти  [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625942/set-dropdown-list-option-with-ellipses), просто создаем порт, для показа `option`, и на него делаем `text-overflow:ellipsis`

Решил проблему при помощи css

> не работает в хроме `text-overflow:ellipsis` для элемента `<option...`

```css
select, select option {
    width:150px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    display: block;
overflow: hidden
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

div {
    border-style:solid; 
    width:150px; 
    overflow:hidden; 
    white-space:nowrap; 
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div style="
    webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -5px rgba(153,148,153,1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -5px rgba(153,148,153,1);
    box-shadow: 0px 7px 9px -5px rgba(153,148,153,1);
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 23px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 69px 69px 69px 69px;
    -moz-border-radius: 69px 69px 69px 69px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 69px 69px 69px 69px;
    border: 0px solid #000000;
    left: 147px;
    top: 25px;
">
          <select style="
    font: 11px Arial;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 27px;
    top: 76px;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding-left: 15px;
    left: 25px;
    border: none;
">
 <option hidden>Выберите марку</option>
   <option>SHORT</option>
   <option>LONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONG</option>
  
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Иногда не умею сформулировать свою мысль...
В общем обрезать опцию я могу, проблема в том, что мне нужно, чтобы при том, как я кликну на нее было так http://joxi.ru/Vm64klztMvLNAZ, но при клике в списке выпадающем все еще находилась полная версия.

Comment: я добавил `value` он не изменяется, так подходит?

Comment: я не про значения, я про текст. То-есть в вып. списке все еще должно быть "LONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONGLONG LONG" видно пользователю

Comment: значит только при выборе должны быть точки?

Comment: да, в окошке выбора, в выпад. списке все еще оставаться полной версией.

Comment: проверьте ответ

Comment: В Хроме не работает, трех точек не видать.

Comment: Добавил Линк на решение, по другому никак